# Incompatible pointer type sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'NSDate *'

Tags: objective-c, casting, objective-c-category

I have an NSDate category with following method

```
@implementation NSDate (DateUtility)

+(NSString *)dateTimeStringForDB {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatForDB = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatForDB setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *aDateStr= [dateFormatForDB stringFromDate:self];
    [dateFormatForDB release];
    return aDateStr;    
}
@end
```

with this definition I receive a warning .

**Incompatible pointer type sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'NSDate *'**

However type casting self  before assign it as argument suppresses this warning.

```
+(NSString *)dateTimeStringForDB
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatForDB = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatForDB setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *aDateStr= [dateFormatForDB stringFromDate:(NSDate*)self];
    [dateFormatForDB release];
    return aDateStr;    
}
```

Can we really not pass self as an argument in a category without typecasting it ?  What is this feature dependent on  , the compiler ? Looking for an answer before actually posting it as a question on SO I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905567/438658), however I am still not clear as to what goes behind the scene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created a class method, I suspect you really want an instance method.  I assume you want to convert an instance of an `NSDate` (ie an object) into an `NSString` representation.  Currently you are trying to convert the actual `NSDate` class into an `NSString` representation.

Change

```
+(NSString *)dateTimeStringForDB {
```

to

```
-(NSString *)dateTimeStringForDB {
```

Comment: Thanks, Don't know why But I just missed that.